# c# inheriting from generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let me describe the logic and then class structure. There are objects and all object must inherit from ConfigurationObjectBase. Each object must be owned by Manager and all Managers must be derived from ConfigurationObjectManagerBase. When a new instance of object created, one of the constructor must accept instance of Manager and that instance of Manager must add that instance of object into it's property called ChildObjects. Below is sample of classes. could you pls help to correct in below code acording above business rule? Thanks.

```
public class ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>
{
    public ConfigurationObjectBase(ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<ObjectType> ownerManager)
    {
        ownerManager.ChildObjects.Add(this);
    }
}


public class ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<ObjectType>
{
    public ConfigurationObjectManagerBase()
    {
        ChildObjects = new List<ObjectType>();
    }

    public List<ObjectType> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

public class Catalog : ConfigurationObjectBase<Catalog>
{
    public Catalog(CatalogManager ownerManager) : base(???)
    {

    }
}

public class CatalogManager : ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<CatalogManager>
{
    public CatalogManager() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- `CatalogManager` should inherit from `ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<Catalog>`, not `ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<CatalogManager>`
- `ChildObjects` should probably be a list of `ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>`, rather than a list of `ObjectType` (otherwise you can't add a `ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>` to it)

So the code should probably look like this:

```
public class ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>
{
    public ConfigurationObjectBase(ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<ObjectType> ownerManager)
    {
        ownerManager.ChildObjects.Add(this);
    }
}


public class ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<ObjectType>
{
    public ConfigurationObjectManagerBase()
    {
        ChildObjects = new List<ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>>();
    }

    public List<ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

public class Catalog : ConfigurationObjectBase<Catalog>
{
    public Catalog(CatalogManager ownerManager) : base(ownerManager)
    {

    }
}

public class CatalogManager : ConfigurationObjectManagerBase<Catalog>
{
    public CatalogManager()
    {
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to call the default base class constructor (`base()`), it's done implicitly by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. The main reason I went for generics to avoid boxing and unboxing. Before generics, defined ChildObjects as List<ConfigurationObjectBase>. So, different type of Managers stored the List of ConfigurationObjectBases and in order to get access specific properties I had to cast that List to desired object. Like: List<Catalog> = CatalogMgr.ChildObjects.Cast<Catalog>().ToList()..  Do you think performance should be OK now? Thanks

Comment: @Tim, hard to say without more context... but at least your code should be more type-safe now.

Comment: (CatalogMgr.ChildObjects.First() as Catalog) - how can I avoid even without specifying "as Catalog"?  Without "as Catalog" it does return ConfigurationObjectBase<Catalog>. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, currently your `ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>` doesn't expose or even contain an `ObjectType`; you'll have to add it. Add a new property of type `ObjectType` and initialize it from an constructor parameter. You'll then be able to do `CatalogMgr.ChildObjects.First().Object` (replace `Object` with the actual name you choose for the property of course)

Comment: If there is "ownerManager.ChildObjects.Add(this);" then what is the reason for adding a new property in ConfigurationObjectBase and type of ObjectType? Logic is that each Manager mush have child objects and each list is specific to type of ObjectType where Manager is defined. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, I don't understand. What is the point of `ConfigurationObjectBase<ObjectType>` if it never does anything with `ObjectType`? At some point, I assume you're going to need to manipulate instances of `ObjectType`, but in your current type there isn't any.